# Mod_Rewrite for Invisible page extensions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need a very simple (for someone else I'm sure) `mod_rewrite` rule that allows leaving off the `.php` extension on the url. So for example

`http://example.com/page` shows content at `http://example.com/page.php`

and

`http://example.com/folder/page` shows content at `http://example.com/folder/page.php`

Are there any rewrite ninjas out there who may know this off the top of their head?

**Edit**
It would be great if any queries could stay exactly the same too. so:

```
http://example.com/page?this=that` shows content at `http://example.com/page.php?this=that
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hurray for [misusing mod_rewrite](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite). Have you tried `Options MultiViews` instead?

Comment: +1 for giving me what I needed, not what I asked for. Thank you.

Comment: I was looking to do a similar thing. Adding "Options +MultiViews" into the .htaccess file worked like a champ. This is a simple site with everything at the root and AllowOverride enabled in the main apache config.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should redirect /page to /page.php, etc

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Do i need a `RewriteCond` for that? I'm new to this.